# ace javascript editor multiple instances

Tags: javascript, performance, ace-editor

I'm working on an interface that uses a digraph to model a software pipeline where each node has associated metadata and (most relevantly) an editable code block.  Right now I'm using ACE for its many code-friendly features, but once the pipelines hit a rather low threshold of complexity ACE seems to grind to a halt, tanking the responsiveness of the rest of the page.

Right now, this is the relevant part of what's happening whenever a new node is introduced:

```
    view.codeDiv = d3.select('#code-section');
    view.aceEditor = ace.edit('task-code');
    view.aceEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome");
    view.aceEditor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/ourMode");
    view.aceEditor.getSession().on('change', function(e) {
        if (view.model !== undefined &&
            view.aceEditor !== undefined &&
            view.model.get('cmd') !== view.aceEditor.getValue() &&
            view.aceEditor.getValue() !== '') {
                view.model.set('cmd', view.aceEditor.getValue());
            }
     });
```

What I'm worried about is that the ACE sessions aren't ever getting closed and aren't playing nice with each other.  I'm experimenting with different timings for declaring them 'uneditable' and hopefully decreasing their memory needs, but the greater structure of the UI makes that difficult.  Has anyone else had any luck trying to improve performance for multiple active ACE instances?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by font size polling https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/layer/text.js#L88